# Simple OddNums IEnumerable

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable

In our studying materials we have an example

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> OddNums(int n)
 {
    int i = –1;
    while (i < n – 1)
    {
       i += 2;  
       yield return i;
    }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    foreach (int i in OddNums(10))      
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", i);
  }
```

However it throws errors on lines

```
int i = –1;
while (i < n – 1)
```

- Unexpected character '–'
- Invalid expression term ''
- ; expected
- Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

What is wrong?

Comment: Please, include error message.

Comment: Note that `-` != `–`. The former is a hyphen, and it's valid for code. The latter is an en dash, and it's not. If changing the latter to the former fixes your issue, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Did you by any chance copy-paste it from the studying materials?

Comment: It was indeed problem caused by copy-paste. There was – instead of -. Thanks

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => i * 2 + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hyphen instead of minus ...

Replace it by minus here:

```
 int i = -1;
```

and here:

```
while (i < n - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are expecting `-` to be a **minus** sign which eventually seems to be a **– hyphen**

Try to change that by deleting it and then typing it again.

```
while (i < n - 1)
```